# How to properly use offset within Twitter's Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use `offset1 span6` for the main content and wanted to apply the same for `navbar` content, but it doesn't work properly - please see [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/fJU4K/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offsets only work within the context of a `.row`, so add the `.row` class to your navbar div and it works just fine.

```
<div class="row navbar-inner"> ... </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fJU4K/1/

Comment: Almost correct ;) As replied on github (https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1994): _The span classes are not meant to be used on the container. Use them on a grid column within a row if you want the intended effect I think you do. See the grid docs for how to use them, under Scaffolding._

Comment: @LA_ hmm, confusing, but "Use them on a grid column **within a row if you want the intended effect**" but doesn't that mean the same in the end?

Comment: I haven't tried your approach, I did `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"><div class="navbar-inner"><div class="container"><div class="row offset1 span7">` and it works well.

Comment: @LA_ just tried your method in the above fiddle i posted, got funky results but it must be because of the setup. But i believe it should be the same, as long as the offset is within a row it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/taZjV/

The trick is to 
a) remove the "offset1 span6" from the row and make it a div of its own, 
b) remove the navbar-fixed-top from the navbar
c) Move the navbar inside the offset1 span6 div

Comment: Thanks, but I that's not exactly what I was looking for - (1) navbar itself now has the offset, when only navbar's content should have it, (2) it is not fixed on the top - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/taZjV/5/. And overall approach doesn't look well - `.container` inside of `.container`.